# Unreal engine C++ UPaperSprite Array?

Tags: c++, sprite

I'm trying to put some sprite in an Array like in my blueprint 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCooa.png)

But it doesn't work and I can't find solution in UE4 documentation
Whent I'm trying to do this:

```
UPROPERTY()
TArray <UPaperSprite*>  spriteArray;
```

I have some errors like this :

> error C2065: 'UPaperSprite'?: Undeclared identifier
>   error C2059: syntax error?: '>'

Thanks you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go `Project->Properties->IncludeSearchPath->Edit`
Enter 3 lines as below assume that your unreal engine is in `D` drive

```
D:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Plugins\2D\Paper2D\Source\Paper2D\Classes
D:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Plugins\2D\Paper2D\Source\Paper2D\Public
D:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Plugins\2D\Paper2D\Source\Paper2D\
```

Now you can include `#include "PaperSpriteComponent.h"`